# UNION SQL Query built on CTE over multiple databases

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, common-table-expression, unions

Using MS SQL 2008 R2,
I have a query that uses cte to build my desired output.  This works fine for one database but now I need to pull the same query over multiple databases and return all those results in one result set. Without extreme detail I have:

```
;with cte1 as ( my query from db1),
cte2 as ( another query from cte1),
cte3 as ( yet another one from cte2)
Select 'db1.Name' as dbName, * from cte3
```

This gives me the data I need with the 1st column having the associated db name.  Now I need to run this over 30+ databases all with the same schema and the same output but when I try this:

```
;with cte1 as ( my query from db1),
cte2 as ( another query from cte1),
cte3 as ( yet another one from cte2)
Select 'db1.Name' as dbName, * from cte3

Union (or Union All)

;with cte1 as ( my query from db2),
cte2 as ( another query from cte1),
cte3 as ( yet another one from cte2)
Select 'db2.Name' as dbName, * from cte3

Union (or Union All)

... till we reach the 30+
```

I get complaints of the ";" and the union/union all.  How do I get all the final select statement output from all the databases into 1 result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CTE](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) do not work this way ..

to solve  problem create global temp table and populate the table and at the end do select .

Ie sample assuming there are two column column1 and column2 are generated from cte3

```
    CREATE TABLE ##result
    ( dbname varchar(50);
      column1 varchar(50),
      column2 varchar(50))


    ;with cte1 as ( my query from db1),
    cte2 as ( another query from cte1),
    cte3 as ( yet another one from cte2)

    INSERT INTO ##result (dbname ,column1 ,column2)
    Select 'db1.Name' as dbName, * into ##result from cte3

     ;with cte1 as ( my query from db1),
    cte2 as ( another query from cte1),
    cte3 as ( yet another one from cte2)

    INSERT INTO ##result (dbname ,column1 ,column2)
    Select 'db1.Name' as dbName, * into ##result from cte3


    select * from  ##result ;
```

Comment: This is what I needed thank you, didn't think to use a global temp table.  Now I just need to get it to work with SSRS :)  Thanks for your help!